# How to automatically jump into the *compilation* buffer after the compilation ending in emacs?

Tags: emacs, compilation

Emacs have a compilation command opening a so called *compilation* buffer displaying the result of the compilation.
I would like to configure emacs to automatically jump into this buffer once the compilation has end (whatever if there is warning or errors).

The purpose of this is that if there is no error, and I want to continue coding closing the *compilation* buffer require either to jump into it  (`C-x o`) and close it (`q`) or close other window (`C-x 1`) which is 3 or 4 hits on the keyboard. If the *compilation* buffer is automatically selected, only one (`q`) is required (or I can go to the error with `RET`).

I saw other related posts but no one address specifically this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your init file: `~/.emacs` (or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`)

`(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'switch-to-buffer-other-window 'compilation)`

`add-hook` Add a function call after `compilation-finish`. The function is explicitly `switch-to-buffer-other-window` and take the parameter `compilation` which is, explicitly again, the name of the *compilation* buffer.